# How better is VSCode for SF development than other paid tools? - need your objective opinion

Tags: apex, vs-code, ide, developer-productivity

This question is aimed to get help to decide whether to migrate to VS Code or stay with IntelliJ+IlluminatedCloud.

I know this is a personal choice, but I feel like I'm being driven more and more to go to V Code, which does every task than my other paid tool (IlluminatedCloud), but I feel like my paid tool helps me better with productivity (based on a guess, not facts, so this is subjective).

So,

1. What tools did you use before VSCode?
2. Do you feel like VSCode fulfill all the needs when coding, smoothly (few clicks and commands)?
3. Do you think that having to learn again how to properly use VSCode is worth it?
4. Last and more important: (please help me in this one) - What can you say about VSCode that could make me say, ok let's go for it?

FYI, I'm already taking the Trailheads for this (especially those for LWC and SFDX).

I guess not having this kind of help it's what keeps my attached to IlluminatedCloud:

[image]
[image]

While for my VSCode is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is opinion-based. I know you tried to limit it to a "VS Code vs IntelliJ" product comparison, but that's still subjective, and not a good fit for this site. As a quick summary, I'll say this: IntelliJ is a mature product, while VS Code is still in development. It should catch up in due time. In the interim, VSC has the ability to install third-party plugins and even allows you write your own, so you can fix whatever problems you perceive with the tool, and then share it easily with others. Also, it's free and cross-platform, which has its own merits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing tools is naturally subjective, as it depends on the features you care about personally. However, as an objective response, I say that VS Code is better than any paid tool.

Allow me to elaborate. Unfortunately, it doesn't yet have a dedicated SOQL Builder, though it can run queries directly from a text file. The auto-completion for Visualforce is admittedly spotty.

However, it does have a lot of (possibly unique) features. it has the Apex Log Replay Debugger, which lets you use debugging tools offline to determine logic errors. It has the Apex Code Debugger, which lets you debug live Apex Code on the server as it is running.

It has a local Lightning Web Component Server that proxies Apex calls to Salesforce, allowing you to test your code locally without deploying to a server. It has pretty solid Apex auto-completion, including your organization's custom objects and fields via the Apex Language Server.

It even allows third-party developers to write their own extensions, and then publish them for everyone to use. All at no extra cost. For the few minor problems it has, Code does load fast, the Command Palette makes learning the IDE a breeze (plus so easy to find the file you want to open), and can even use all node modules (npm), such as installing a custom Apex Code formatter.

It's hard to justify a $500/year cost per developer to use a tool when you can get a tool like Code for $0/year cost per developer. The minor setbacks that do still exist are being addressed, it's simply that this tool is not as mature as others that have been around a decade or longer, so it has had to play catch-up.

That said, compare the features of your favorite paid IDE to VS Code, you'll find that you're paying a lot of money for a few bells and whistles that you could write yourself if you wanted to. The only real reason not to switch is if it's missing that one "killer feature" that you have to have. And odds are, it'll be here sooner than you think (#SafeHarbor, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I have a friend/coworker who has used IntelliJ for a long time but is slowly making the switch as well. Aside from the extensions (oooooh, so many), it bears mentioning that VS Code is the tool Salesforce itself is officially endorsing and developing for.

On the extensions front, I recently found one that flags PMD warnings (https://pmd.github.io/latest/), which has already helped me improve the quality of my code. There's also Prettier, and SF projects in VS Code ship with default Prettier and ESLint rules which helps with code quality and visual formatting/readability. I don't know that those are exclusive to VS Code, but as a beginner dev they are quite useful tools and the level to which they're integrated makes them very easy to use.